# Why does a plot of a reciprocal function using pgfplots look wrong?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I am trying to plot the function `1/x^2` but the result is obviously wrong, here is how it looks like

[image]

here is the code

```
\begin{center} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[ 
    %xlabel=$x$,
    %ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}   ] 
    \addplot[blue] {1/(x^2)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're dividing by nearly zero, so that result is in a way expected. You could use `restrict y to domain=0:20` to remove all y-values larger than 20, or (easier) just add `ymax=25` to set the maximum value for the y-axis.

The difference between the two is that the former removes all calculated y-values that are outside the given domain from the plot, while the second just sets the axis limits. With the latter, the lines will extend to the axis.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = 1/x^2$},
    restrict y to domain=0:20,
    ] 
\addplot[blue,samples=200] {1/(x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = 1/x^2$},
    ymax=20
    ] 
\addplot[blue,samples=200] {1/(x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This works fine.....

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%
    [
        grid=major,  
        x=5mm,
        y=5mm,
        xtick={-10,-9,...,10},   
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10,
        xlabel={\tiny $x$},
        axis x line=middle,
        ytick={-10,-9,...,10},
        tick label style={font=\tiny},
        ymin=-10,
        ymax=10,
        ylabel={\scriptsize $f(x)$},
        axis y line=middle,
        no markers,
        samples=100,
        domain=-10:10,
        restrict y to domain=-20:20
    ]
    \addplot[thick,samples=400] (x,{1/x^2});
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]